# Google Maps API using markers as links?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm pretty new at using the Google Maps API although I've learned a lot about it over the last week but one thing that is still bugging me is that i don't know how to add a marker event so that when i click on a mark it will send me to a website. I want the marker to say for example take me to Google(http://www.google.ie/) when i click on it.

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {

       });
```

I just don't know what to put inside this function to do this, i have two events on each marker one with I mouseover the marker, that works alright its just the click that I want to get working.

Answer (score 0):

GEvent.addListener is an event listener (exactly what it says). It look for you to do something, in this case a click. When you call addListener, you're also creating a function.

Within the function, you can call in anything you want. Typically, most people opens up the infoWindow which describes the marker, but in your case, you can put in:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

so your entire code could look like:

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                   window.location = "http://www.google.com";
       });
```

A quick FYI, I did not test out the code.